Timeline can't be set to start in a negative frame
I enabled the option 'Allow negative frames' in the Preferences, but it's not working. I can only set the current time to a negative frame, but not the timeline start.
What do I do? I suspect there might be an add-on troubling Blender's code.
So my questions are: how do I know if there is an add-on interfering? And do sdy know a script to allow negative frames?
Thanks!

That is the intended behaviour

You say it yourself in your question: "I can only set the current time to a negative frame" and when you hover your mouse over the option it says "Current frame number can be manually set to a negative value" - so how is it not working?
There is no intention in the software to have animations start at negative frames, because some softwares and output formats like some video files for example do not allow negative frames or image sequences with negative frame numbers.
This goes for the Rendering Range though. However, Blender allows you to set a Preview Range as well. You can use it by enabling the Use Preview Range button (the clock or stop watch symbol next to the Start value of the Timeline):

In the default use, the Timeline area is grey, with everything outside the Rendering Range being darker than what is within the range. After enabling the Preview Range, the Timeline gets a brownish overlay and now only the Preview Range will be grey, indicating that this is now the range which will be shown/looped when you run the animation.
The Preview Range can be useful when you want to focus on a certain range to be looped to only see this, especially when the actual Rendering Range is very long and you do not want to watch everything all over again. But at the same time the Rendering Range stays untouched and you do not have to adjust Start and End frames several times between previewing something and rendering everything - and more importantly, starting a long animation to render overnight with Ctrl+F12 only to find out the next morning that all you got is 50 frames somewhere in the middle because to forgot to change the values of the Rendering Range back.
Now, to cut a long story short: when using the Preview Range, you can use negative values for the Start (and even the End) frame. Running the animation will then play the negative frames as well. You can also use the jump to start/end shortcuts Shift+⇦ and Shift+⇨ to jump to negative frames even when Allow Negative Frames is not enabled. But to manually access them or any other negative frames inbetween, the option has to be enabled.
Now you might ask why is there an option to allow negative frames when you cannot render them? I do not know all use cases, but just to give you ideas:

You have downloaded a character animation like e.g. a walk cycle which loops 100 frames. But you want to begin it somewhere inbetween so you move it over to the left of the timeline, in the negative range. This works without a Preview Range, however now you want to tweak some keyframes in the negative range. Sure, you can move the complete animation in the positive range, change the keys and move them back into the negative range, but that is not very comfortable - accessing the negative frames directly is more convenient.

Smoke simulations can be set to start on a negative frame. This can be used to avoid the sudden "blob" of smoke on the start of a simulation and have the smoke continuously flowing already when the actual animation starts (same with a liquid simulation if you want a body of a water to calm before the animation). Now these simulations can be affected by collision objects which can also be animated, and maybe you want them to already affect the simulation  before the "real" animation starts and need to tweak keyframes in the negative range as well.


Surely you can come up with more possible uses, for example the one whatever it is why you need this option. By the way, although "proper" rendering does not render negative frames, View > Viewport Render Animation does. But you cannot play the negative frames back afterwards with Ctrl+F11 because the render playback only uses the positive frames.
Another problem with playing back the negative frames could be the order. In Blender's file browser a frame range from -0003 to 0003 is sorted:
-0001, -0002, -0003, 0000, 0001, 0002, 0003
In my Windows Explorer they are sorted like this:
0000, 0001, -0001, 0002, -0002, 0003, -0003
The only solution I see to this sorting issue would be to rename the files to all positive frame numbers, but then the question would be, why bother creating an animation with negative frames in the first place?

Thanks! The idea is to settle simulations before beginning to shot the animation. You said the smoke sims can be set to negative frames. But only by performing the cache right? I think it would be more useful to have animations from negative frames, like Maya. The naming of the files could be set not by timeline but by chronological order.

@AAAYerus For me personally I cannot see any advantages in negative frames (apart from things like settling a simulation etc. and even then I could just start rendering later), but I never needed the real animation to start earlier then frame 0 or 1. This combined with possible incompatibilites with some formats... And yes, you have to use the disk cache for a negative start of the simulation - because if you cannot play negative values, you cannot use Replay to simulate on negative frames "on the fly".

@AAAYerus Anyway, I can only tell you how it works in Blender... if other methods would be useful or more convenient or even necessary is out of the scope of this site, since we are just users trying to help users working with Blender. We are no developers, not making any development decisions and in no way part of the Blender Foundation.
